# "Open in remote terminal" for Xubuntu file manager

Tags: 13.10, nautilus, xubuntu, xfce4-terminal

I recently switched to Xubuntu. I am trying to recover the Ubuntu nautilus functionality, "Open in remote terminal", which was on the right-click menu of every file manager window. This does not appear in Xubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The following suggestion should work.

(Tested on Xubuntu 14.04 client connected over ssh to Xubuntu 14.04 ssh server)

**Create a new custom action on the Xubuntu ssh server:**

[image]

[image]

Command:

```
xfce4-terminal -x bash -c "bash"
```