# Thunar, open in terminal does not work in sftp or ftp

Tags: command-line, thunar

Thunar has "Open terminal here" option just like nautilus when you install "nautilus-open-terminal" package. My problem is it does not work when I connect to sftp. I need this very often. How do I enable it?

Using UbuntuStudio 14.04.

Comment: You can try this http://askubuntu.com/a/476145/265974

Comment: That did not work. Maybe I will be installing nautilus... I miss the 2 panes, too, anyway.